# YouTube API. rel: 0 и loop: 1 - не работает

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player_promo = new YT.Player('DIV_ID', { 
    videoId: 'VIDEO_ID',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    playerVars: { 
        'autoplay': 1,  
        'controls': 0, 
        'showinfo': 0, 
        'loop': 1,  
        'playlist': 'VIDEO_ID', 
        'rel': 0, 
        'enablejsapi': 1,
        'origin': 'URL'
    }
});
```

Видео воспроизводится, но не по кругу и показывает похожие в конце. Раньше работало. В документации всё так, как написал я. Может что-то не так?

Answer (score 0):

Кусочек документации [отсюда](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=ru)

> **loop**
>
> **Примечание**. Этот параметр имеет ограниченную поддержку в проигрывателе AS3 и при встраивании IFrame для загрузки проигрывателя
> AS3 или HTML5. **В настоящее время параметр loop работает только в
> проигрывателе AS3**, если он используется в сочетании с параметром
> playlist. Чтобы закольцевать одно видео, установите для параметра loop
> значение 1, а для параметра playlist укажите тот же идентификатор
> видео, что и в URL Player API:

Comment: У меня ID видео и playlist одинаковое и всё равно не работает. Нашёл другое решение

Comment: Если ответ не помог опубликуйте то что помог

Answer (score 0):

```
events: { 
    'onStateChange': function(e) {
    if (e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        player_promo.playVideo(); 
    }
}
```

Решение такое сработало

Comment: Да конечно тоже вариант